# wget all files from folder skip first 10000 files or so

Tags: file, wget, transfer

I am transferring files from a folder on one server to another and I am using wget to do so.
But the problem is that wget gets terminated and when I rerun the command it starts from the very first file although I use `-nc` to skip files that exist but still it traverses all the files and then skip those files that exist so it takes too much time in skipping the files.

I want to know is there any way to have wget start downloading directly from the new file instead of checking each file from the top.

I hope I have made my question clear. Pardon me if couldn't.

This is the command that I am using:
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p -nc  http://www.example.com/images/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a reject-list to skip already downloaded files.

If all your files are in the same directory, it could be as simple as:

```
wget -R "`ls -1 | tr "\n" ,`" <your own options>
```

I am not sure what will happen with partial downloads.